# Processing Code "Error, disabling_serialEvent() in Arduino

Tags: macos, arduino, processing, osx-mavericks

I receive this error when trying to run my arduino and Processing

```
Error, disabling serialEvent() for /dev/cu.usbmodem1451 null
```

I am running process 2 and Arduino 1.6.5 on a MAC OSX 10.9.5

I am super new to processing and arduino . I am just trying to use three potentiometers to control the RGB values of the background color.

Arduino code:

```
int potPin = 0;
//int potPinB = 1;
//int potPinC = 2;

void setup() 
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int val = map(analogRead(potPin), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  Serial.println(val);
  delay(500);
  //int valB = map(analogRead(potPinB), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  //Serial.println(valB);
  //delay(50);
  //int valC = map(analogRead(potPinA), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  //Serial.println(valC);
  //delay(50);
}
```

Processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial port;

float val = 0;
//float valB = 1; // another analog input
//float valC = 2; // another analog input

void setup() 
{
  size(500, 500); 
  port = new Serial(this, "/dev/cu.usbmodem1451", 9600);
  port.bufferUntil('\n');
  if (frame != null); 
  frame.setResizable(true);
 }
void draw () 
{
background(val,255,150);
}
void serialEvent (Serial port)
{
  val = float(port.readStringUntil('\n'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting an error in serialEvent which you should be handling (perhaps the float conversion). Also, if you're using `bufferUntil()`, you shouldn't need `readStringUntil()`.

Try something like this:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial port;

float val = 0;
//float valB = 1; // another analog input
//float valC = 2; // another analog input

void setup() 
{
  size(500, 500); 
  port = new Serial(this, "/dev/cu.usbmodem1451", 9600);
  port.bufferUntil('\n');
  if (frame != null); 
  frame.setResizable(true);
 }
void draw () 
{
background(val,255,150);
}
void serialEvent (Serial port)
{
  try{
    val = float(port.readString());
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

When simply reading a single value, [readChar()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_readChar_.html) or simply [read()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_read_.html) should work.

If the above works. You should be able to send multiple values.
Initially you can send a csv like formatter line:

```
arduinoR,arduinoG,arduinoB\n
```

which you can then read as a string, [split()](https://processing.org/reference/split_.html) it into an array of 3 values, then convert each array element from String to int.
**Update**
Here an example:

```
import processing.serial.*; 
int r, g, b; 
void setup() { 
  try { 
    new Serial(this, "/dev/tty.usbmodemfa141", 9600).bufferUntil('\n');
  }
  catch(Exception e) { 
    println("check settings above and usb cable, something went wrong:"); 
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
} 
void draw() { 
  background(r, g, b);
} 
void serialEvent(Serial s) { 
  String data = s.readString(); 
  try { 
    String[] rgb = data.trim().split(",");
    print(rgb);
    if(rgb.length == 3){
      r = int(rgb[0]); 
      g = int(rgb[1]); 
      b = int(rgb[2]);
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Later on you can look at sending data as binary: exactly 3 bytes (r,g,b).
Have fun :)

Comment: So I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. I rewrote the arduino code. I am just not sure how to have processing read the string to output the background color.
 int potPin = 0;
int potPinB = 1;
int potPinC = 2;

void setup() 
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int val = map(analogRead(potPin), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  Serial.print(val);
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(",");
  int valB = map(analogRead(potPinB), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  Serial.print(valB);
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(",");
  int valC = map(analogRead(potPinC), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  Serial.println(valC);
  delay(500);
}

Comment: I won't be able to test right now, but can you try this? ```import processing.serial.*;
int r,g,b;
void setup(){
  try{
    new Serial(this,"/dev/tty.usbmodem1451",9600).bufferUntil('\n');
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("check settings above and usb cable, something went wrong:");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }    
}
void draw(){
  background(r,g,b);
}
void serialEvent(Serial s){
  String data = s.readString();
  try{
    String[] rgb = data.split(",");
    r = int(rgb[0]);
    g = int(rgb[1]);
    b = int(rgb[2]);
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}```

Comment: @EricWillmann check the update. I've tested the code with an Arduino and it works. Be sure use the correct serial port on your computer

Comment: So I tried the code. Everything works great except the blue channel. I made sure the arduino was outputting values and it was working correctly. I even switched the pins to make sure.

Comment: Also the serial works either way 
{ try{ new Serial(this,"/dev/cu.usbmodem1451",9600).bufferUntil('\n');
also works this way
{ try{ new Serial(this,"/dev/tty.usbmodem1451",9600).bufferUntil('\n');

Comment: Here is my updated code
import processing.serial.*;


int r,g,b; 
void setup() 
 {
  size(500, 500);
  if (frame != null); 
  frame.setResizable(true); }
  { try{ new Serial(this,"/dev/cu.usbmodem1451",9600).bufferUntil('\n');
   }catch(Exception e){ println("check settings above and usb cable, something went wrong:");
   e.printStackTrace(); } 
}
void draw () 
{ 
background(r,g,b); 
}
void serialEvent(Serial s)
{
  String data = s.readString();
  try{ String[] rgb = data.split(",");
  r = int(rgb[0]);
  g = int(rgb[1]);
  b = int(rgb[2]);}
catch(Exception e)
  { e.printStackTrace();}}

Comment: I was getting the blue channel when I tested last week. I won't be able to test at the moment, but I recommend printing the data coming the serial port as soon as you read it (e.g. ```println(data);```). If the full string looks ok(includes the blue channel), print how the look after it gets plit (e.g. ```println(rgb);```). Also, I noticed the ```try``` block in which you initialize the Arduino is outside of the ```setup()``` method, but that shouldn't interfere with the data received though.

Comment: Sorry I am super new at this how do I read it after I (e.g. println(rgb);)? I can see it reads correctly out of arduino.

Comment: let's break it down: in serialEvent() you first call readString() and store the result in the data variable. You can print that on the following line and see if the blue channel data is part of the original data coming from Arduino. If that happens, we move onto the next step, otherwise, there's something weird with the Arduino code not sending the blue channel to begin with. The next step is when you split the string: ```String[] rgb = data.split(",");```. On the following line, you can do ```println(rgb);``` which should print an array of strings. You need to check that the blue channel data

Comment: I can see that there are values for the "b" value on the serial monitor on the Arduino. So I added the println(rgb); and I do see a change. But there isnt a visual change to the screen.

Comment: I even tried changing the pin for the arduino and the "b" value doesn't visual show. My serial monitors on both processing and arduino show the value changing.

Comment: I do get this copy in red on the processing. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at RGB.serialEvent(RGB.java:45)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at processing.serial.Serial.serialEvent(Unknown Source)
 at jssc.SerialPort$LinuxEventThread.run(SerialPort.java:1299)

Comment: :)) that is your explanation right there: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2". So you're splitting the string(e.g. ```32,64,127```) by the "," symbol which should be an array with 3 elements: ```{"32","64","127"}```. What the error is saying is you are trying to assign the blue value by accessing the 3rd item in the array: (index 2), but the array you have doesn't have 3 elements. Can you post the output for ```println(data);``` and ```println(rgb);``` ? (by the way, when printing the rgb array, you should see square brackets with array indices for each value.)

Comment: Here is the println from the arduino. 122,46,255
80,1,255
80,76,175
80,76,77
80,178,78
89,197,78
83,197,78
83,197,77 and here is the println data from processing 83 197 78

83 197 78

83 197 78

83 197 78

83 197 78

83 197 78

83 197 78

83 197 78 so no commas on the processing. is this the problem?

Comment: And where is the end of the line after 3 values ? what is the output for ```println("data: "+data);``` after you get a single reading ?

Comment: sorry I dont follow. where am i looking for println("data: "+data);?

Comment: This is what I see on processing 83 197 78
 Then in goes to the next line

Comment: The issue seems related to parsing the 3rd value so we need to check what the source of the problem first: is it how the data comes in Processing or how Processing splits the incoming string into an array. This is probably where it gets confusing because we're doing 2 things one after the other. Let's focus on one thing at a time: If you send 83,197,78 in Arduino, do you see 83,197,78 ? (let's say if you only did this: void ```serialEvent(Serial s) { 
  println(s.readString());}``` ) Does it make sense what we're testing and how ?

Comment: So the arduino outputs     111,168,41 and processing reads it the same way 111 168 41 no commas

Comment: I don't understand why Processing drops the commas (that didn't happen to me). At least you get the spaces, so you can split on those instead. This means instead of ```String[] rgb = data.split(",");``` you would do ```String[] rgb = data.split(" ");```. Try doing this in your code and let me know how it goes

Comment: When I do    String[] rgb = data.split(" "); nothing works it doesn't read anything.

Comment: I did try println(r+","+g+","+b);     The commas did show up but then it wouldnt read the blue value at all. It would stay at zero.

Comment: The arduino code reads the value. right now it reads 179,168,74 and processing reads 179,168,0

Comment: I meant your full Arduino code so I can replicate your setup. Processing is now displaying the commas ?

Comment: int potPin = 0;
int potPinB = 1;
int potPinC = 4;

void setup() 
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int val = map(analogRead(potPin), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  Serial.print(val);
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(",");
  int valB = map(analogRead(potPinB), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  Serial.print(valB);
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(",");
  int valC = map(analogRead(potPinC), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  Serial.println(valC);
  delay(500);
}

Comment: Here is my processing code.  import processing.serial.*;
//Serial myport;
int r,g,b; 
void setup() 
{ try{ new Serial(this,"/dev/tty.usbmodem1451",9600).bufferUntil('\n');
}catch(Exception e){ println("check settings above and usb cable, something went wrong:");
e.printStackTrace();} 
{
if (frame != null); 
frame.setResizable(true); }}
void draw () 
{ 
background(r, g, b); 
}
void serialEvent(Serial s)
{
  String data = s.readString();
  try{ String[] rgb = data.split(",");
  println(r+","+g+","+b); r = int(rgb[0]);g = int(rgb[1]);b = int(rgb[2]);}
catch(Exception e)
  {e.printStackTrace(); }}

Comment: Ok, found the issue. The Arduino code is fine(although you might want to add a single delay after you do the println(), otherwise the 2nd and 3rd potentiometers will always lag compared to the 1st). The main issue is parsing the string and especially the fact that the 3rd value also has the new line character, which is why the string needed to be [trimmed](https://processing.org/reference/trim_.html) first. so ```data.split(",")``` becomes ```data.trim().split(",")```. To break it down: you're sending r,g,b\n then in Processing you buffer until \n, but don't remove it, so...

Comment: ...after you split by , you would have {r, g, b\n} . b\n is two character that won't convert to int which is you always get 0. you would've noticed an extra line when you called println(). Does this make sense ?

Comment: Totally works now Thanks a bunch. one last question I see there is a function to change the brightness as well. Is that as simple as adding another potentiometer and assigning a value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83995/discussion-between-george-profenza-and-eric-willmann).