# How do I change the background in Processing from an Arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, processing, rgb

I am trying to use three potentiometers that are connected to an Arduino to adjust the color background of Processing. I am super new at this.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
int potPin = 0;
int potPinB = 1;
int potPinC = 2;

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    int val = map(analogRead(potPin), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
    Serial.print(val);
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(",");

    int valB = map(analogRead(potPinB), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
    Serial.print(valB);
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(",");

    int valC = map(analogRead(potPinC), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
    Serial.println(valC);
    delay(500);
}
```

Here is my processing code:
Which I know is wrong. My screen just shows up black.

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
float val = 0;

void setup() 
{
    size(500, 500); 
    port = new Serial(this, "/dev/cu.usbmodem1451", 9600);
    //port.bufferUntil('\n');

    if (frame != null); 
    frame.setResizable(true);
}

void draw () 
{
    background(val);
}

void serialEvent (Serial port)
{
    val = float(port.readStringUntil('\n'));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aurdino + Processing Code "Error, disabling\_serialEvent()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392341/aurdino-processing-code-error-disabling-serialevent)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be using linux, you may want to check this:

*"/dev/cu.usbmodem1451"* -> mine is -> *"/dev/ttyUSB0"*

Here's an example I made from your posted code. It works on my machine, let me know if you have any difficulties.

**Arduino Sketch (same)**

```
int potPin = 0;
int potPinB = 1;
int potPinC = 2;

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    int val = map(analogRead(potPin), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
    Serial.print(val);
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(",");

    int valB = map(analogRead(potPinB), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
    Serial.print(valB);
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(",");

    int valC = map(analogRead(potPinC), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
    Serial.println(valC);
    delay(500);
}
```

**Processing Sketch**

The processing sketch has been changed, some code was taken from the [Arduino - Graph](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/graph) tutorial.

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;        // The serial port
int xPos = 1;         // horizontal position of the graph

void setup () {
  // set the window size:
  size(400, 300);        

  // List all the available serial ports
  println(Serial.list());
  // Open whatever port is the one you're using.
  myPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600);
  // don't generate a serialEvent() unless you get a newline character:
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  // set inital background:
  background(0);
}
void draw () {
  // everything happens in the serialEvent()
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  // read first string
  String inStringA = myPort.readStringUntil(',');

  // make sure it's not empty
  if (inStringA != null){
    // read following strings
    String inStringB = myPort.readStringUntil(',');
    String inStringC = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');

    // convert to an int and map to the screen height:
    float valA = float(inStringA); 
    float valB = float(inStringB); 
    float valC = float(inStringC); 
    // assign to rgb background
    background(valA,valB,valC);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using a Mac. I will try this code once I get back on my computer. Thanks for your input

Comment: So I tested the code with my correct serial port. It only reads the blue value nothing else. Here is my updated Processing code:

Comment: import processing.serial.*;
Serial myport;
void setup() 
{
size(500, 500); 
println(Serial.list());
myport = new Serial(this, "/dev/cu.usbmodem1451", 9600);
myport.bufferUntil('\n');
if (frame != null); 
frame.setResizable(true);
 }
void draw () {}
void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
String inStringA = myPort.readStringUntil(',');
if (inStringA != null){
  String inStringB = myPort.readStringUntil(',');
  String inStringC = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  float valA = float(inStringA); 
  float valB = float(inStringB); 
  float valC = float(inStringC); 
  background(valA,valB,valC);
  }
}

Comment: Just the blue channel is working? It could be the physical configuration of the potentiometers. Create an "Test arduino sketch" which just display's the value to the Arduino Serial Display. Just check that all the potentiometers are outputting varying values.

Comment: I check the arduino and The serial monitor shows the values correctly. I turned the knobs and the all change accordingly.

Comment: Here is my updated code.
import processing.serial.*;
int r,g,b; 
void setup() 
 {size(500, 500);
  if (frame != null); 
  frame.setResizable(true); }
  { try{ new Serial(this,"/dev/tty.usbmodem1451",9600).bufferUntil('\n');
   }catch(Exception e){ println("check settings above and usb cable, something went wrong:");
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}
void draw () 
{ 
background(r,g,b); 
}

void serialEvent(Serial s)
{
  String data = s.readString();
  try{ String[] rgb = data.split(",");
  r = int(rgb[0]);
  g = int(rgb[1]);
  b = int(rgb[2]);
  }
catch(Exception e)
 { 
 e.printStackTrace(); 
  }}